# Adobe cirrus android application exit/restart without any errors

Tags: android, apache-flex, adobe, terminate, adobe-cirrus

Greeting.

I'm currently working on a crossplatform test project that involves adobe cirrus for video chat and such. The application is written in Flash builder 4.6 standard (no profiler option) in flex and A3  and the target platform is Windows and Android.

Both use the same code and strangly the windows version works well without any freeze/unespected termination, but the android one somtimes just quit out of the application back to the android homescreen after using the video chat. And when i reselect the application window, it seems like it has restarted.

I tried to run the application in "debug" mode on the device, but there's no error poping up when the application crash/exit just a "terminated, exit value: 0" message.
I'm using resource monitor app to monitor memory and cpu to check if it's a out of memory issue, but the app seems to use a stable 60-70mb of the memory leaving about 280-300mb left and the cpu is at the highest on 80%.

I also tried to alter needed phone "right" to everything, even if I really only need phone wifi state, internett and camp&mic.

I'm not running any other apps beside the resource monitor and the test app when testing.

So any clues?